# Count the number of elements in a list of lists with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to use some LINQ in my C# code to improve readability.

Given

```
private IDictionary<T, ICollection<E>> myDict;
```

a Dictionary with collections as values, how to determine the total amount of elements in all collections with LINQ?

```
public int AmountElements 
{
   get
   {
     return ??;
   }
}
```

Comment: var results = myDict.Select(x => new { key = x.Key, count = x.Value.Count() }); var results2 = myDict.Sum(x => x.Value.Count());

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the total number of elements in the dictionary values:

```
myDict.Values.Sum(collection => collection.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
var count = myDict.SelectMany(d => d.Value).Count();
```

So you can write your `AmountElements` property as follows:

```
 public int AmountElements => myDict.SelectMany(d => d.Value).Count();
```